# IText object disappear when I use clipPath in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to use a clipRect for IText object, but when I use clipPath, the IText object is disappeared

```
const clipPath = new fabric.Rect({
    top: 100,
    left: 100,
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
    fill: 'white'
  })

  object.value = new fabric.IText('跑馬燈文字', {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fill: '#000000',
    fontSize: 16,
    clipPath
  })

canvas.value.add(clipPath)
canvas.value.add(object.value)
canvas.value.renderAll()
```

here is my demo code

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-fermi-lkzxx5?file=/src/App.vue